# nodejs: Getting whole day time range in local time zone

Tags: node.js, datetime, utc

We keep our time in UTC and in nodejs, is there an easy way to get time range to a local time zone?

For example, 27 Sept 00:00AM to 27 Sept 23:59PM UTC represents a full day in UTC BUT not in local timezone in Australia.

In Australia, it would be 26 Sept 14:00 UTC - 27 Sept 14:00 UTC.

Is there an easier way to get 14 hour other than hard coding it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have found a module to do that.

Putting it here for the benefits of others:

[moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/)